# What is preferable way to send param to async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an doubt related to android Async task .Is it preferable to send params required for async in  async's constructor or should  i add it on execute() method????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not mandatory, but as AsyncTask is designed to pass parameter in execute method, You should pass parameters to execute method, it will invoke onPreExecute method with same parameter, and there you can do your initialization tasks.

Comment: thnax for quick reply but is there any performance related issue if i pass param in constructor not in execute()

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to pass them in execute. It is more straight forward that way.

Answer (score 1):

As we uses java, generally passes parameters in `constructor` and initialize them in constructor.

But it is not compulsory, you can pass it in `execute()` also.

But as i thinks better to pass in `constructor` because whenever class of async task is created a constructor will called first.

Answer (score 0):

[`execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) is the place where you pass the parameters.

You may use the constructor to pass something *more general and not specific to a certain task*. For example, passing your context to hold a reference to your UI (eg. progressBar).